# ManyToOne double select hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Parent` table with a single `id` field as the PK and a `Child` table that has its own `id` as the PK and a parent_id column that references the `id` in the `Parent` table as the FK.

Suppose I have 4 ids in my `Parent` table and I have 4 rows in the `Child` table like these:

```
| id | parent_id |
  1      1
  2      2
  3      3
  4      3
```

As you can see, the `Parent` id with value '4' has no childs.

The mapping of the `Parent` table is a simple pojo with a single field, the `Child` entity is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
    
    // getters & setters
}
```

From java code, i run this query:

```
TypedQuery<Child> practicesQuery = dataBaseContext.getCurrentSession().createQuery(""
    + "FROM Child c WHERE c.parent.id = :id", Child.class).setParameter("id", id);
    return practicesQuery.getResultList();
```

I tried running it for the first 3 ids and hibernate generated 2 select statements for each "fetch" operation like these:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        child0_.id as id1_59_,
        child0_.parent_id as parent_i3_59_ 
    from
        child child0_ 
    where
        child0_.parent_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        parent0_.id as id1_111_0_ 
    from
        parent parent0_ 
    where
        parent0_.id=?
```

but when I run the same query for the id = 4 only the first query is exectued.

Why does hibernate tries to get those parents that has some childs (with id 1,2 and 3) but doesn't execute a select statement for the parent that doesn't have childs (with id 4)? Of course the second select is always useless in this scenario.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default fetching strategy for @ManyToOne relation is EAGER. Since you are using a default fetch strategy for the parent filed, Hibernate is triggering the second query on parent table to load the parent record.

From [JPA specification](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) the default fetch type for @ManyToOne relation is

```
public abstract FetchType fetch
(Optional) Whether the association should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that the associated entity must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.
Default:
    javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER
```

In case if you don't want to eagerly load the parent object, set the fetch type to lazy

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: I guess that when I need the parent entity then I simply query it, right?
I'm wondering if it would ever make sense to keep the EAGER fetch type on a scenario like this.. Are there any advantages so far?